# Align link bottom and right

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to move the green link so that it's sitting on the line like the span. This is my HTML

```
<div class="adminpanel-span" id="approved-users">
  <span>Approved Users</span>
  <a href="https://google.com" style="clear:both;float:right; font-size: 18px;" target="_blank">Download List</a>
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.adminpanel-span {
  font-size: 36px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I've looked at other posts and found how to get it to the right, but I couldn't find how to bring it down to the line. How can you position the link on the line?

Comment: `vertical-align: bottom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.adminpanel-span {
  font-size: 36px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.adminpanel-span > a{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="adminpanel-span" id="approved-users">
  <span>Approved Users</span>
  <a href="https://google.com" style="clear:both;float:right; font-size: 18px;" target="_blank">Download List</a>
</div>
```

Try to use `postion: absolute` and `position: relative`

Comment: This works if I get rid of the style within the <a> tags. Thanks for the help!